# How to write explicit wait until a particular WebElement is located

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is a sample code for the explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath-here")));
```

I want to pass WebElement as a parameter in method and wait until that WebElement is located:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(MyWebElement));
```

I am not sure whether such option is already there and can be done in a different way as in my case I am getting an exception as I am passing WebElement in place of `By.xpath("")` which is not the correct way.

Comment: How is going? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is working, thanks '

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `visibilityOf` expected condition.

The code will be like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(MyWebElement));
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This should nail the OP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot pass the web element in place of XPath because the method 'visibilityOfElementLocated()' will accept only By locator.

Suppose, your method is like below :

```
public static void waitUntilLocated(WebDriver driver, int waitingTime, By locator) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, waitingTime).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
}
```

Then You can store the By locator like below :

```
By someXPath = By.xpath("some xpath here");
```

Then you can pass 'By locator' to the method as a parameter

```
waitUntilLocated(driver, 30, someXPath);
```

Below is the whole code :

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test1 {

    public static void waitUntilLocated(WebDriver driver, int waitingTime, By locator) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, waitingTime).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }

    public static void main(String ...ali) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:1234/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Alicse3"+Keys.ENTER);

        // Checking element is located or not?
        By someXPath = By.xpath("some xpath here");
        waitUntilLocated(driver, 30, someXPath);

        // Checking some other element
        By someId = By.id("some id");
        waitUntilLocated(driver, 30, someId);
    }
}
```

Or you can do like below if you want to pass Web Element to the method and don't want to use 'visibilityOfElementLocated()' :

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test1 {

    public static void waitUntilLocated(WebDriver driver, int waitingTime, WebElement element) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, waitingTime).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }

    public static void main(String ...ali) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:1234/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Alicse3"+Keys.ENTER);

        // Checking element is located or not?
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Some XPath"));
        waitUntilLocated(driver, 30, element);

        // Checking some other element
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("Some ID"));
        waitUntilLocated(driver, 30, element);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps...